# unattended cygwin setup without setup.ini

Tags: cygwin

I´m doin a unattended cygwin installation and I was wondering if there will occure any problems without a setup.ini.

Following: my "install-folder" includes a setup.exe and a subfolder release (within all the packages packed).
I´m starting the setup silent (with Nsis) and install the packages. In NSIS I define the Root, the location of the packages etc.

I think it works so far (I´m not sure because i´ve got a curious error in cmake). There are many instructions how to modify the whole setup for an offline installation. But I don´t get the point why I have to modify it at all.

I hope anyone has got experience with this issue!

@Daniel Le cygwin installs the packages without the .ini (all of them). And there has nothing to be downloaded because the packages are on the local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ini file is so far only a description for file locations and paths to be set as default. It is not necessary to have the ini file if you wanna install some packages!

That´s my conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the setup.ini is essential to the setup process, as it indicates which packages to be downloaded and installed.